# Custom RichTextBox and Text Property Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, richtextbox

I have created a custom `RichTextBox` control and exposed a `Text` property. The `Text` property is defined as follows:

```
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd).Text; 
    }
    set
    {
        AppendText(value); 
        OnPropertyChanged("Text");
    }
}
```

The `RichTextBox` is using a `ViewModel` as `DataContext` as shown below:

```
<WPF:SharpRichTextBox MaxCharactersAllowed="100" NotificationStyleName="defaultTextBlockStyle"
                      Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                      DefaultNotificationStyleName="textblockStyle" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                      Background="Yellow">
</WPF:SharpRichTextBox>
```

Now I want that whenever I change the `Text` of the `RichTextBox` the `Name` property in the `ViewModel` gets updated. How can I do that?

Comment: Why in the world a RichTextBox?